# How to load specific url in Webview programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to make a basic search tool in cocoa. I am trying to take the string from a textfield, edit it to make a link that searches the string in google, and then feed that into the WebView. However, Xcode is not letting me use the variable I made for the Web View. I'm getting errors along the lines of "Unknown type name 'WebView'" and "Bad Receiver type '*int'". Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code for
NewWindowController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NewWindowController : NSWindowController
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSComboBox *searchselector;


- (IBAction)onclickGO:(id)sender;
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webv;






@end
```

NewWindowController.m:

```
#import "NewWindowController.h"

@interface NewWindowController ()

@end

@implementation NewWindowController
@synthesize searchselector, webv;

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Window did load");
}

- (IBAction)onclickGO:(id)sender {
    NSInteger *indexofsearch = [searchselector indexOfSelectedItem];
    NSLog(@"%d",indexofsearch);
//test for web view to load page
[[webv mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL  URLWithString: @"https://google.com"]]];


}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebView` is part of `WebKit.framework`, which is not included in the default projects.

- Add `@import WebKit;` to the top of whatever file you're referencing the `WebView` object in.
- Add WebKit.framework to "Link Binary with Libraries" (in Build Phases)